# How to Format an LVM partition

Tags: rhel, lvm, mkfs

I need to format a partition.

But I have one LVM on my machine (VirtualBox) that is composed of **two different two partitions of two Virtual HDD**'s (sdb5 and sdc5)

fdisk output [image]

df output

[image]

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question.
Is that VirtualBox on a Logical Volume, or a Logical Volume within VirtualBox? How many Volume Groups? How were they created, ie from which Physical Volumes?

Comment: Redhat is running on Virtual Box

Comment: So RH is on VBox. What OS is VirtualBox running on top of? You initialize "Physical Volumes" with pvcreate, then group PVs into a "Volume Group". From a volume group you create "Logical Volumes" each of which may be formatted with any file system you chose. The issue is that if you created the Volume Group/Logical Volumes from the OS running VirtualBox, then you need to manage the VG/LV from that OS, not from the VBox client OS, it will be dealing with virtual disks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LVM doesn't change the way you format a partition. Let's say you would have a volume group called `group1` and a logical volume called `volume1` then your command should look like this for ext3:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/group1/volume1
```

In case you don't have any volume groups or logical volumes yet, you have to use the according LVM tools to create them. The manpages of `vgcreate` and `lvcreate` can tell you how to do that.

Comment: No I have Volume Group and LV

Comment: in that case you just use the normal mkfs tools on the device you want to format. the lvm devices are presented as /dev/lvgroup/lvolume

Comment: i just saw your df output only now. on your case the device for your logical volume should be /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00

Comment: For some reason before posting question it mkfs said that device is in use when I already unmounted the partition. But now its ok Thanks for giving me info